# JSON Response is coming on Genymotion (Emulator) but not on actual device (My android phone)

Tags: android, json, android-studio

This is my async task which is retrieving JSON, it works fine on Emulator but when I try to retrieve it on actual phone it does not work

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
        String Json_url;
        String json_String;
        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
           Json_url = "http://192.168.10.9/UANProject/uanjson.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(Json_url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while((json_String = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(json_String+"\n");

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();

                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;``
            }
```

This is were the result is shown when its running on gennymotion the result is shown but when on actual device the result is not shown in the textview , not showing any error nor any exception

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJsonResp);
            tv.setText(result);

            Json_String = result;
        }
```

Comment: Can your real device connect to your local server ?
Your Virtual device might be connected to local server but the real device is not connected to it. Check and let me know if it worked

Comment: check your current ip address and put instead of 192.168.10.9

Comment: There is some problem with your url. I am getting timeout exception when I tried your code

Comment: Is the `Json_url` you are is on local host or actual server. please open browser in your device and copy paste the `Json_url`. check the response then.

Comment: @Vivek i am running it on my local server.  i.e XAMPP

Comment: I tried but it dosent worked for me @Sathish

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Local Server. host the code on server and check